# "for each of the two" in German?

Tags: english-to-german

I would like to say "for each of the two" in German in a context sort of like

> however, I do not know whom I should contact for each of the two courses.

The only way I could think to translate this was

> Jedoch weiß ich nicht, wem ich jeweils für die beiden Kurse anschreiben soll.

However, "jeweils für die beiden" returns few Google hits which confirms my suspicions that it's not correct German. So how do I best translate "for each of these two" into German?

Comment: It's "*wen* ich anschreiben soll", not *wem*

Comment: Other than that, the sentence is fine from my point of view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use

> Jedoch weiß ich nicht, wen ich für die beiden Kurse jeweils anschreiben soll.

Answer (score 0):

Florian Diesch's answer is correct, but usually people talk a little more sloppy:

```
Jedoch weiß ich nicht, wen ich für beide Kurse jeweils anschreiben soll.
```

Answer (score 0):

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9144/dative-whom-with-accusative-who

using accusative instead of dative , its correct to say:

> however, I do not know who I should contact for each of the two
>   courses.

however to contact is not "ansprechen".

> however, I don't know who I should contact, in order to get
>   informations regarding each of the two courses.

ansprechen is more like "to talk to"

> Jedoch weiß ich nicht, wen ich für die beiden Kurse jeweils
>   kontaktieren muss.

Comment: *Whom* in proper written English.